# Разный typeof в chrome

Tags: javascript

Использую библиотеку amcharts. В chrome в режиме инкогнито код `console.dir(typeof chart.categoryAxis.getCoordinate());` выведет `number` и все ок. В режиме обычного просмотра этот же код становится `undefined`. В другим браузерах все ок, кэш чистил. С чем еще может быть связано такое двойственное поведение?

Comment: с тем. что в одном случае вызов `chart.categoryAxis.getCoordinate()` возвращает число, а в другом `undefined`

Comment: Я смог выяснить что довольно много расширений на это влияют. Возможно обеспечить приватность данных всей библиотеки? без паттерна "модуль"?